# In "Bones of Faerie", what happened with Rebecca's shadow and her mother, Tara?

Tags: janni-lee-simner

In *Bones of Faerie*,

> Tara is very ill from radiation poisoning. Rebecca had died and Liza had (unknowingly) called her back as a shadow.

Tara reaches out for Rebecca and Liza gives Rebecca to her mother.

> The shadow sank into Tara and disappeared, and Tara's fever went down.

What happened here and how did Tara do this?  (Tara had no magic....)